# Why Pull to Refresh does not stop?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, pull-to-refresh

I am caching data online from API and then store it in Have DB. Everything works well until when it comes to refreshing the data by `Pull to Refresh` widget. When I pull the screen down to refresh the data, the `CircularProgressIndicator` widget starts circling endlessly, so the data does not update. Please look at the code provided below and let me know what the problem is. Thanks!
Code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List stories = [];
  late Box storyBox;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> openBox() async {
    final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(document.path);
    Hive.registerAdapter<Item>(ItemAdapter());
    storyBox = await Hive.openBox<Item>(storyBoxName);
    return;
  }

  Future<bool> getAllData() async {
    await openBox();
    const url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      await putData(extractedData);
    } catch (SocketException) {
      print('NO Internet');
    }
    var mymap = storyBox.toMap().values.toList().reversed.toList();
    if (mymap.isEmpty) {
      stories.add('Empty');
    } else {
      stories = mymap;
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  }

  Future putData(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    await storyBox.clear();
    Item newStory;
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      newStory = Item(
        title: value['title'],
        category: value['category'],
        content: value['content'],
        author: value['author'],
        id: key.toString(),
        date: DateTime.parse(value['id']),
      );
      storyBox.put(key, newStory);
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateData() async {
    const url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      await putData(extractedData);
      setState(() {});
    } catch (SocketException) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Shaparak'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getAllData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (stories.contains('empty')) {
                return const Text('No Data');
              } else {
                return RefreshIndicator(
                    child: ItemsGrid(stories as List<Item>),
                    onRefresh: updateData);
              }
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using the keyword "return" at the end of your tasks inside updateData? That method needs to tell the Future that is done in order for the RefreshIndicator to be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

FutureBuilder's snapshot parameter also contains a `snapshot.hasError` that tells you if an exception was raised inside the future function. You can check if `snapshot.hasError` is true and display a `Text(snapshot.error)` to see what the error was.

Right now you are not making use of this error if it is happening. My guess is that you are getting and ignoring an error there.

I bet `getAllData()` is not completing correctly. Do you have any errors in your logs? You can try to add `print('here');` kind of lines at the end of `getAllData()` and see if it actually executes till the end.

Comment: The error says: "HiveError: There is already a TypeAdapter for typeId 1."

Comment: Yes, so your immediate problem is that your getAllData() is raising an exception and not actually returning any data. You should figure out how to use hive correctly. Then, as Passy and Mariano mentioned, there are other issues with your code as well. You should take things one at a time, make hive work in a much simpler code and then make it more complex.

Comment: I fully agree with you, but I don’t know how to correct the code. Can I ask you, if possible, to bring the necessary edits to the code?

Comment: I think getAllData() is called multiple times. Actually @Passy's answer would help you here. Hive.init() is called multiple times and you probably get this error because it is not closed. The immediate action could be to close hive at the end of getAllData(). I don't know Hive much so I can't tell how.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setState()` in `updateData()` the `build` method is called. This causes your `FutureBuilder` to call `getAllData()` *again*.

Instead of calling `getAllData()` in your build method, call it in `initState()` at the beginning and save the data into the box.

Use a `ValueListeneableBuilder` to show the data directly from the box, and it will update when you update the box content

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: storyBox.listenable(),
  builder: (context, box, widget) {
    // TODO get stories from box
  },
)
```

Comment: would you please expand your explanation by writing the code on how I can get stories from box in the builder method at the body? I am a beginner and I don't know what to do. Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: I faced an error: "LateInitializationError: Field 'storyBox' has not been initialized"

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, never call `setState()` in a `Future` function if you're going to be calling that function with a `FutureBuilder` in your build method because it WILL trigger an infinite loop.

More technically, `setState` will trigger a rebuild of the `build` function which means the `FutureBuilder` will be rebuilt and call that `future` you passed in that contains `setState` and `setState` will rebuild the `build` method again before that `future` completes which will start the `FutureBuilder` all over again, and it keeps going on like that forever...

**To fix the endless loading:**

In your `updateData()` method, remove `setState()` and everything else should work just fine.